# what is cpu intensive task in pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hive, cpu, cpu-cores

Working on `pyspark, Hive and Hadoop`

is there any relation between input/output channels and no. of cores(cpu).
What I understand is

```
1 core = 2 channels = 1 input channel and 1 output channel.
```

if this is the case then 
    while writing dataframe to table, output channel will be busy writing data to `hadoop/hive`. since output channel is associated with core(CPU) Can I call it CPU intensive process ?
if this is not the case 
        then please let me know what actually is CPU intensive task especially in `pyspark`

Comment: No, I'd say no. A CPU intensive task is a task limited by the availability of a CPU resource. Writing to the DB is not CPU intensive. The channel is probably a TCP/IP connection between the containers and the Spark application master. It doesn't limit the parallelism. I'm not even sure if Tez, the DAG engine under Spark, assigns a task to a logical CPU if another task is still running on it (i.e. something like a cooperative multi-threading). So more than one channel is probably pointless.